# Multiple notifications with one status bar icon in android

Tags: android, notifications

i am using custom notification...how can i set no of notification is showing?and list out those notification?
this is my code...

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "coming", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle descBundle = intent.getExtras();
        CharSequence desc = descBundle.getString("description");
        int reminderId = descBundle.getInt("reminderId");
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                reminderId, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.main);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.reminder_1);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, desc);
        Notification notifyDetails = new Notification();
        notifyDetails.icon = R.drawable.reminder_1;
        notifyDetails.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notifyDetails.tickerText = desc;
        notifyDetails.iconLevel = 1;
        notifyDetails.number = reminderId;
        notifyDetails.contentView = contentView;
        notifyDetails.contentIntent = contentIntent;
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notifyDetails);
    }
```

i am using this code to show the notification...but it shows only one notification content...but icon shows no of notification...

Comment: can we add the multiple notification in that manager?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that if you want show multiple notify for different objects, you have to assign a different Notification ID for each one.

For example, if you have 2 different objects, you have to call

```
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notifyDetails);
```

and

```
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notifyDetails);
```

If you don't do that, Notification will be always one and will be always updated.

Answer (score 2):

Each icon corresponds to one notification; you cannot associate multiple notifications with one instance of an item on the notification bar.

You can, however, overlay a number on top of your icon (e.g. to show the number of events that icon represents) like some SMS and email applications do.

This is done with the `number` instance variable of `Notification`, as you have in your code snippet above.

**Edit:**
To be more clear: If you want multiple notifications, you need to create multiple `Notification` objects and call `NotificationManager.notify()` multiple times.

Each `Notification` can only produce one icon, can have one piece of content inside the notification area, and can have one `Intent` associated with it.

Comment: I tried "number" variable but that too shows single notification.

Comment: @100rabh: I edited my answer to be more clear about saying you can't do this.